Is there any motivation for defining reflexivity of a homogeneous relation differently from, e.g., symmetry or transitivity?
I noticed that reflexivity[1] seems to differ from other properties of relations, insofar as it is not possible determine whether a relation is reflexive from the graph, alone.
For example, let $A_1 = \{1, 2\}$ and $A_2 = \{1, 2, 3\}$ be sets and define the (graph of the) relation $R_1 = \{ (1, 1), (1, 2), (2,2) \}$, then $R_1: A_1 \to A_1$ is reflexive, but $R_1: A_2 \to A_2$ is not.
By contrast, the other properties seem to focus on the graph, itself. For example, $R_2 = \{ (1, 1) \}$ is (vacuously) transitive and symmetric whether defined on $A_1$ or $A_2$ (whereas it is not reflexive in either case).
It seems possible to define reflexivity analogously, e.g. I think either:
$$\forall (x,y) \in R, (x, x) \in R,$$
or:
$$(x, y) \in R \implies (x, x) \in R,$$
would skirt this issue.
So I'm left wondering if there is a reason that would motivate the common definition over this alternative (which, to me, seems more aligned with the form of the other properties)? Is there any advantage?

[1]: I'm assuming what I believe to be standard definitions: given a set $A$ and a relation $R: A \to A$, $R \subseteq A \times A$

when $\forall x \in A, xRx$, we say $R$ is reflexive.
when $\forall x,y \in A, xRy \implies y R x$, we say $R$ is symmetric.
when $\forall x, y, z \in A, xRy \land y R z \implies x R z$, we say $R$ is transitive.


I don't see how this would skirt the issue (that I don't think is a real issue).  If you say $(x,x)$ must be in $R$ whenever $(x,y) \in R$ this still doesn't recognize that $(3,3)$ should be in $R_1$ for $A_2$ as $3$ never occurs as a coordinate.

@Randall I meant "issue" in the sense of "the point being discussed" not in the sense of "a problem that must be resolved". Specifically, it gets around reflexivity being defined in terms of the domain of the relation as opposed to the graph, like the other properties. Perhaps I should've said: "eliminates the difference from the other definitions".

I guess my point is your new definition still wouldn't recognize that $R_1$ isn't reflexive on $A_2$ based on the graph alone.

Yes, the definition of reflexivity depends on the purported domain of the function, while symmetry and transitivity don't. But why is this an issue? In mathematical practice, we are generally interested in some specific domains (so we write things of the form "$R$ is reflexive on $X$").

@Randall that is exactly the point I'm making. The proposed definition would define reflexivity analogously to symmetry and transitivity.

@RobArthan Thanks for both replies. Re: "issue", see my response to Randall, above. I was just curious why reflexivity would be singled out in this way (domain-dependent) when it isn't necessary. Does it serve some purpose? Or is it totally irrelevant because we can always consider the relation over a different domain? I guess I would expect that, if it doesn't matter, the convention would be to chose the form that is structurally similar to the other properties, instead of one that introduces an exception which serves no purpose.

To me, it makes no sense to speak of a relation without specifying the domain first.  The domain is part of the package.

@Randall, that's still besides the point. As commonly defined, transitivity, symmetry etc are not domain-dependent, but reflexivity is (unnecessarily so). Whether you define the domain first or not is immaterial to that distinction.

I guess I don't see transitivity as not domain-dependent.  Even when you say $(a,b) \in R$ you are saying that $a, b \in A$ (the domain).  By your own definition $R \subseteq A \times A$.  At any rate, I see what you are saying about reflexivity, I just don't see the need to reinvent everything.

@Randall transitivity isn't domain dependent because the logical statement requires that both conjuncts be true. So, e.g., even the empty set defines a transitive relation on either $A_1$ or $A_2$. Again, I'm not suggesting there is a problem: I'm pointing out a difference. In my experience, mathematicians don't introduce differences unless they serve some purpose. The purpose in this case is not clear to me. Based on Rob's reply, I'm guessing it's just for historical reasons and there is no benefit to the standard definition.

Since $R \subset A \times A$ the relation will be reflexive if every vertex in the digraph has a loop.

Your proposed definition of reflexivity yields what are often called "partial equivalence relations." These occur commonly enough to often be referred to simply as "pers".  They serve a slightly different purpose than equivalence relations.  An equivalence relation on a domain $D$ can produce a quotient of $D$, while a per on $D$ produces a quotient of a subset of $D$.
